# How to get next div when I use BeautifulSoup .findAll?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I work with BeautifulSoup in python2.7 I have code like this:

```
html = "<div>\
  <div>\
      <div>\
          <div>one</div>\
          <div>\
              <div>two</div>\
              <div>three</div>\
              <div>four</div>\
          </div>\
          <div>five</div>\
      </div>\
  </div>\
</div>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
currency = soup.findAll('div')
```

to get content `one` i use

```
print currency[1].div.div.contents
```

how to get all other: two, three etc.?

Answer (score 3):

When you get to the `one` div, get the [*following `div` sibling*](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling) and then all `div` elements inside:

```
one = currency[1].div.div
for elm in one.find_next_sibling("div").find_all("div"):
    print(elm.get_text())
```

Prints:

```
two
three
four
```

Comment: I can't do this directly without any loops etc? I try currency[1].div.div[2].contents but it's doesnt work :(

Comment: @MastaBot how about a list comprehension: `[elm.get_text() for elm in one.find_next_sibling("div").find_all("div")]`?