# How to use beautiful soup to extract Wikipedia links in a specific section?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the URLs in **See Also** section of the Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy_law.

I have tried the following code:

```
url_req = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy_law"
response = requests.get(url=url_req,)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

snippet = soup.find_all('h2')
for headline in snippet:
    if re.findall('see.{0,5}also',str(headline),re.IGNORECASE):
        links = headline.findall('a')
print(links)
```

I am able to locate the correct headline but not able to reach the URLs. They are in a `<div>` after this specific `<h2>`. How to get these URLs?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the id `#See_also`, select its parent to get to the `<h2>`, then use [`.next_sibling("div")`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35069125/6243352) to find the container for the links:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy_law")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
links = (
    soup
    .select_one("#See_also")
    .parent
    .find_next_sibling("div")
    .find_all("a", href=True)
)
print([x["href"] for x in links])
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the wikipidia library:

https://wikipedia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

this is an example for the library

```
wikipedia.search(query, results=10, suggestion=False)¶
```